# Python typewriter effect issues

Tags: python

```
string = "Your NEW name is ALBY. You have 3 minutes to get to your shelter or you get RIPPED APART by gamma radiation and A MASSIVE FIREBALL. Do you RUN, SHELTER, or WAIT?"
for char in string:
print(char, end='')
time.sleep(.05)
print("")
time.sleep(5)
answer1 = input("What do you do?")
while True:
if answer1 == "RUN":
  print("")
  print ("You choose to RUN. Within minutes of running you see a massive 
FIREBALL behind you, say your PRAYERS and DIE.")
  print("")
  time.sleep(5)
  print("You Died! The creator of this game can't use 'While True' 
statements and therefore you must restart.")
elif answer1 == "WAIT":
  print("This is certainly not YOUR BEST IDEA. You WAIT for the bomb to drop 
and DIE a hot death.")
  print("")
  time.sleep(5)
  print("")
  print("You Died! The creator of this game can't use 'While True' statements and therefore you must restart.")

elif answer1 == "SHELTER":
  def slowprint(s):
    for c in s + '\n':
      sys.stdout.write(c)
      sys.stdout.flush() # defeat buffering
      time.sleep(random.random() * 0.1)

slowprint('Hello, world.')
```

Above is the code snippet, i have the typewriter effect going for a little text adventure. When I run the code all that happens is i get a blank loop, or the first letter of the line.

[EDIT: This isn't a duplicate of a flushing issue. I didn't want to flush slowprint i just needed to redefine it.]

Comment: A better place to ask to review your code is there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Comment: @AndrewD. No, it's an actual bug.  `stdout` isn't being flushed when needed.

Comment: If you want the for loop to work you can use `print(char, end='', flush=True)`

Comment: Why do your code snippet contain a lot of irrelevant parts that are not even correctly indented?